# How to solved problem with telegram bot api in nextjs

Tags: node.js, next.js, telegram-bot

I have a problem with my nextjs application: the problem lies in a function whose purpose is to send information to the telegram through the bot api url, locally this works perfectly without any type of problem but when I pass it to production it stops working , so I think it is a type of lock or permission that I must unlock in vercel, although in the vercel console it does not print anything

```
import { sprintf } from "sprintf-js";

export default class Telegram {
    constructor(postID, title, imgURL) {
        this.postID = postID
        this.title = title
        this.imgURL = imgURL
    }
    sendMessage() {
        let message = sprintf("%s - %s", this.title, this.postID);
        fetch(`https://api.telegram.org/bot${process.env.TG_TOKEN}/sendMessage`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                text: message,
                chat_id: process.env.TG_CHATID,
                parse_mode: "html"
            })
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
    }
}
```

here is the call to the function:

```
import Telegram from "../telegram"
...
let post_tg = new Telegram(post["_id"], post["name"], "")
post_tg.sendMessage()
```

This works locally, in production it does nothing, I would like to know how to solve this. I don't know if it is a permission that I should apply in vercel (firewall) or something, I used this code in wordpress and it worked well but it was in another hosting service so for that reason I think, but I still can't know what types of permissions I should unlock or add in vercel since the documentation doesn't tell me anything about this.

I thank you in advance for the guidance and help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

same here, `next dev` works fine with `webhookCallback(bot, 'std/http')`, but fails by 10sec timeout in prod when next is running as a build done by `next build && next start`

im using grammy.js (latest), nextjs (latest)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35507581)